# Database size Widget

Tags: widgets, database, admin, statistics

Is there any way to show the database size on a WordPress Admin Area widget?

I don't want it at the top or bottom of the page, i need it in my widget I'm creating.. Thanks.

Comment: You question is how to create a widget or how to have the database size ? to create a widget look here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Comment: I've created a widget with other functions, But can't find the script to display database size.

Comment: This is a MySQL question then it's rather a question for the site Stack Overflow : https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to your widget code:

```
function fileSizeInfo($filesize) {
    $bytes = array('KB', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');

    if ($filesize < 1024) 
        $filesize = 1;

    for ($i = 0; $filesize > 1024; $i++) 
        $filesize /= 1024;

    $dbSizeInfo['size'] = round($filesize, 3);
    $dbSizeInfo['type'] = $bytes[$i];

    return $dbSizeInfo;
}

function databaseSize() {
    global $wpdb;
    $dbsize = 0;

    $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SHOW table STATUS");

    foreach($rows as $row) 
        $dbsize += $row->Data_length + $row->Index_length;

    return fileSizeInfo($dbsize); 
}

$dbSize = databaseSize();

echo "<b>Database size</b> = {$dbSize['size']} {$dbSize['type']}";
```